# Showing that a map $x \to \|x\|$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

I am given this:

Consider a real Banach space $X$ with norm $\|*\|$.

1) Show that the map $x\to \|x\|$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Is it uniformly continuous?

2) Show that the maps $(x,y)\to x+y$ from $X \times X$ to $X$ and $(c,x)\to cx$ from $\mathbb{R} \times X$ to $X$ are continuous. (On $X \times X$ take the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$. On $\mathbb{R} \times X$ take the norm $\|(c,x)\|=|c| + \|x\|$).

---

I know that normally to show continuity at a point $x_0$, you want to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0$ such that:

$$|x-x_0|\leq \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq \epsilon$$

So I was thinking that I can set $f(x)=\|x\|$... but other than that, I am confused how to begin attacking this problem. Tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the reverse triangle inequality: $$\big|\|x\|-\|y\| \big| \leq \|x-y\|.$$

Comment: So using that trick, would it go something like:
$\big|\|x\|-\|y\| \big| \leq \|x-y\| \leq \| \big|x-y\big| \| = \| \delta \| = \delta$

Comment: @user3784030 Note that $\delta$ is a non-negative real number and not an element of the Banach space $X$, i.e. $\|\delta\|$ doesn't make sense (the same applies to $\| |x-y|\|$). But I guess you mean the right thing: If $\|x-y\|<\delta$, then the reverse triangle inequality shows $$| \|x\|-\|y\| | \leq \|x-y\|<\delta.$$

Comment: So using this, how would I show that
$|x-x_0|\leq \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq \epsilon$

Comment: @user3784030 Set $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Comment: @user3784030 Alternatively, have a look at the definition of Lipschitz continuity and recall that any Lipschitz continuous function is continuous.